# How can I add newline("\n") on Dialog.alert(textfromxml)?

Tags: blackberry, newline, blackberry-widgets

this '\n' doesnt work. Also I tried with LabelField and TextField. Result is same.:(
my code:))

```
 Dialog.alert(errorString);
```

and my xml line.

1) Check your camera's ip address and port number.'\n'2) Try Again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I use `&#xA;` for \n. It works good.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String errorString = 
    "1) Check your camera's ip address and port number.\n2) Try Again";

Dialog.alert(errorString);
```

Comment: @atasoyh: Ok, may be you just expect a 2 new lines.. Try this: `String errorString = "1) Check your camera's ip address and port number.\n\n2) Try Again";`

Comment: :) I know create a new lıne with '\n'. Also I can create newlines with using with a string var. My question is this '\n' character doenst work like it should be when I use with xml.

Comment: @atasoyh: OMG.. Please, next time try to ask in a more clear way. Because now I see it was impossible to understand your real trouble. It turns `Dialog.alert()` has actually no relation to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work, you can implement your own Dialog class. Just do like this:

`Dialog d = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK,"your message here",Dialog.OK, Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.EXCLAMATION), Screen.DEFAULT_CLOSE);`

//you can add customized fields here, like a LabelField

d.show();